# Python regex for capturing all strings like (\w\s)+

Tags: python, regex

I need to capture all strings like (\w\s), with a minimum length of 3, with a Python regex for findall method. This is: to find as many "words" (substrings) as possible, which are composed of a concatenation of at least 3 .

For example, for:

```
This is an e x a m p l e about T H I S question.
```

findall should return:

```
["e x a m p l e ", "T H I S "]
```

Already tried with:

```
\S\S+(\w\s+){3,}\S+
```

Comment: What is `A` in `A\s`? Is it an uppercase letter?

Comment: Wait, *what* do you want to match? Add more examples.

Comment: Did you try your regex first? https://regex101.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following approach with specific regex pattern:

```
s = 'This is an e x a m p l e about T H I S question.'
result = re.findall(r'\b((?:\w\s){3,})', s)

print(result)
```

The output:

```
['e x a m p l e ', 'T H I S ']
```

Comment: thumbs up for a problem that appeared easy and wasn't. Could you explain more about the `?:` part (non-consuming backward stuff or something).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, welcome. without non-capturing group `(([\w]\s){3,})` , besides the outer group, it'll grab the unneeded last part of each  full match giving the result `[('e x a m p l e ', 'e '), ('T H I S ', 'S ')]`

Comment: that the problem I had when I was trying to answer that one.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, I also had to change the approach, because the initial sentence implied only uppercase crucial words. But, that's ok, anyway

Comment: I love those kind of seemingly trivial and first downvoted questions that bring good answers.

Comment: A good answer to a seemingly straight forward question. Upvoted!